# Use video inside carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

There is a not answered topic that is very similar to my problem here:
[HTML carousel with youtube videos stop roatation until end of video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005955/html-carousel-with-youtube-videos-stop-roatation-until-end-of-video)
That's why I decided to ask new question:
How can I use video inside of Bootstrap Carousel in the way  the next slide of the carousel will be shown only after the video file ends?
Basically, I have a simple carousel here:

```
<div class="slider carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" id="video">
      <video id="video" muted autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
        <source src="assets/video/welcome.mp4"></source>
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/img/slide-2.png" alt="Slide 2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-layout"></div>
  <div class="slider-caption">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-orange">Signup now</button>
    <button type="login" class="btn btn-default btn-transperent">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items) fix for the item with ID video:

```
#video{
  -webkit-transition: 23s ease-in-out left !important;
     -moz-transition: 23s ease-in-out left;
       -o-transition: 23s ease-in-out left;
          transition: 23s ease-in-out left !important;
}
```

Here, 23s is the duration of the video. Does anyone know how to implement this functionality? I did not find any answers on this questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#video').on('ended', function () {
  $('.carousel').carousel('next');
});
```

If you use autoplay on carousel you can set interval for video:

```
<div class="item active" muted autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto" id="video" data-interval="999999999">
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Just there is a need to remove loop atribute, cause the video will be played infinitely.